# CS-Cart admin panel stopped working

Tags: php, cs-cart

My cs-cart admin login stopped working suddenly without any change. Giving Error "**You are not allowed to access this area**"
Before few days we enabled access_restriction addon it worked after enabling that addon but now it suddenly stopped working.
We also tried to directly update cscart_addons table and set the addon status "D" disabled. Still no luck.
I am not that good in cs-cart is there someone can help me on this.

Comment: Now again after clearing cache www.mysite.com/admin.php?cc It started working.

Answer (score 0):

Just change or delete app\addons\access_restrictions folder and disable **status** of access_restrictions add on from table cscart_addons  and empty the three more table 
**cscart_access_restriction
cscart_access_restriction_block 
cscart_access_restriction_reason_descriptions**